# JS select2 multiple selector tokenSeparators not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need to replace the standart separator from "," to whatever else.. for example ";" but whatever I tried it doesn't work at all.
Here is my code:

```css
#test{margin:55px;display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="form-control test res_comment set_services">
<option data-trener="13" data-price="10.00" value="Trener 13">Trener 13</option>
<option data-trener="14" data-price="10.00" value="Trener 14">Trener 14</option>
<option data-trener="15" data-price="10.00" value="Trener 15">Trener 15</option>
<option data-trener="16" data-price="10.00" value="Trener 16">Trener 16</option>
</select>

<a id="test" href="#">TEST</a>
   <script>
   $('.test').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: '',
    tags: true,
    allowClear:true,
    tokenSeparators: [';'],
    separator: [';'],
    //maximumSelectionLength: 2,
    insertTag: function (data, tag) {
    // Insert the tag at the end of the results
    data.push(tag);
    },
    placeholder: 'select'
    });
  
  $('#test').click(function(){
   alert($('.test').val());
   })
  </script>
```

Any help appreciated!

JS fiddle works better
[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2sz1jmpq/)

Comment: The real issue is unclear. The code you shared for some unknown reason sets the style `span, texarea{width:100% !important;}` so that the "tags" size get screwed and the correct behaviour doesn't show up. If you removed that css rule alone (and added `width:100%` to the select), the code would work as expected: while typing, when you hit `;` it correctly adds the tag as typed that far and will keep accepting input for the next tag. So I ask: are you aware of what `tokenSeparators` is aimed at? and did you get that sizing problem I highlighted before?

Comment: I don;t have sizing problem, removed the styles ! tokenSeparators is to separate the tags..

Comment: please before continuing I need to be sure you understand everything I said in my previous comment. I observed myself that just removing that rule and expanding the size of the `<select>` the code will work according to the expectation. So I think you have sizing problems.. otherwise that snippet you have there would show something without overlapping elements.  yes `tokenSeparators` is aimed at separate tags ... while typing them in the input. And I observed it works. So I need to ask: what do you mean saying that it doesn't?

Comment: Diego, the tokenSeparators doesnt work. When you click on TEST link you will see that tags || options selected are separated by "," not by ";" as it is supposed to work when specified tokenSeparators. And I dont see what else the styling could do except styling :)
Just click on TEST link to see how the selected options are being printed..

Comment: finally it's clear what you meant. As I was suspecting, you didn't get the meaning of `tokenSeperator`. It's not what you think. The value of the dropdown is actually an array that when type coerced to string will return a comma separated list of values. That's what you are doing there when passing `.val()` to `alert()`

Comment: [This](https://select2.org/tagging#automatic-tokenization-into-tags) is the doc for `tokenSeparators` that is working as expected in your code. If you meant to return a string having `;` as separator you should just process the array doing: `$('.test').val().join(';')`

Comment: Wow, true, changing to $('.test').val().join(';') gives me what I was looking for :) Thanks Diego, please post it as answer so I can accept it as correct ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the dropdown is actually an array that when type coerced to string will return a comma separated list of values. That's what you are doing there on  `alert($('.test').val());`.

If you fetch the dropdown value processing the array like this:

```
return $('.test').val().join(';')
```

It will return a string with the list of selected option values separated by `;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

> The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating
> all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated
> by commas or a specified separator string. If the array has only one
> item, then that item will be returned without using the separator.

As a side note, this is the [reference](https://select2.org/tagging#automatic-tokenization-into-tags) for the `tokenSeparators` that was already working correctly.